# How to load MKMapView only once?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview

I have my map view embedded in a navigation controller, which has a bar button that segues to a table view, and the table view does the same back to the map view.  But if I was zoomed in to a particular position on the map, went to the table view, and came back to the map, it will then reload from scratch and animate back to the default position and i'll lose the zoomed position I was at.  How can I make the map view static between segues to and from the table view?

Comment: Use a shared instance of `MKMapView`.

Comment: Where in your code is created the map view ?

Comment: in the view controller